# Scala syntax ##

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

Please explain what is the meaning of **term.##** in following scala snippet. This is a snippet from apache spark.

[Scala documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#the-null-value) says that ## returns zero. However, being a beginner I am not able to relate here.

```
/**
* Returns the index of the input term.
*/
@Since("1.1.0")
def indexOf(term: Any): Int = Utils.nonNegativeMod(term.##, numFeatures)


/* Calculates 'x' modulo 'mod', takes to consideration sign of x,
* i.e. if 'x' is negative, than 'x' % 'mod' is negative too
* so function return (x % mod) + mod in that case.
*/
def nonNegativeMod(x: Int, mod: Int): Int = {
val rawMod = x % mod
rawMod + (if (rawMod < 0) mod else 0)
}
```

Comment: Check the definition of `##` of `Any` http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/index.html#scala.Any@##():Int

Comment: @mfirry Thanks. It is exactly the page I was looking for.